# how to call a function after calling next function jQuery galleria plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Iam using jQuery galleria plugin and want to do some manipulation after calling next function of jQuery pluugin.Is there any way such that i can call my own function after next function of jQuery galleria plugin gets executed.
Any help in this would be really greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `loadfinish` event, which

> Triggers every time Galleria has finished loading an image

so

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.bind("loadfinish", function(e) {
        // do what you want here
    });
});
```

[Docs for Events here](http://galleria.io/docs/api/events/)